# How to setup failure strategy when adding an actor to the ActorySystem

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm running Play, and I add to the ActorSystem my main CarActorSupervisor that then goes ahead and creates other actors in the hierarchy etc.

```
@Singleton
class Jumpstart @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) {
   val carSupervisor = system.actorOf(CarSupervisor.props(.......))
}
```

Just for testing purposes I threw an exception in my CarSupervisor actor, and all the child actors were stopped but the CarSupervisor was not restarted.

Where am I suppose to setup the failure strategy for my main CarSupervisor actor?

This CarSupervisor actor connects to remote services, so I want it to try and restart and gradually increase the time (backoff time) if it keeps failing.

So in my Jumpstart class, I will startup 3 different "supervisor" type classes.

**But currently if the carSupervisor crashes, it just continues but doesn't try and restart it.  Looking for some sample code on how to do this since I will have 3 actors created from the "root" actorSystem.**

Comment: See this chapter http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/supervision.html#_user__The_Guardian_Actor which explains how top-level actors are supervised. Your choices are either to configure the user guardian actor or introduce another layer with an actor that just supervises your CarSupervisor.

Comment: please read this http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fault-tolerance.html it will be helpfull

Comment: @jrudolph I probably should be creating another layer since the system actor is used by play also, do you have an example creating another layer via my own supervisor?